# Image filter Navigation

Tags: javascript, html

I have all the code and seems okay to me but when I click on the navigation links the link is directed to index.html or the landing project. How do I make the links filter the images?

This is the Javascript and html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").click(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr("data-filter");
    if (name == "all") {
      $(".filter").show("2000");
    } else {
      $(".filter").not("." + name).hide("2000");
      $(".filter").filter("." + name).show("2000");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="portfolio">
  <div style="text-align: center">
    <div class="navigation">
      <a href="" data-filter="all" class="button active">ALL</a>
      <a href="" data-filter="one" class="button">ONE</a>
      <a href="" data-filter="two" class="button">TWO</a>
      <a href="" data-filter="three" class="button">THREE</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ImageContainer">
      <div class="filter one">
        <img src="img/beach.jpg" width="400px" height="250px">
      </div>
      <div class="filter one">
        <img src="img/Windows.jpg" width="400px" height="250px">
      </div>
```

I expected my images to filter but they navigation links are not working

Comment: I think it would be better to use actual [buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Have you identified the reason why the images are not filtering?. But I can try using buttons and find out.

Comment: I suggest taking @jonatjano's advice but to answer your question add a "#" in the href

Comment: I've added the #tags but still directing the links to index.html. I'm kinda new to programming. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default action of the link and also change your numbers to numbers (remove the quotes around the 2000)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").click(function(e) {  // pass the event back into the function
    e.preventDefault();             // prevent the link action
    var name = $(this).attr("data-filter");
    if (name == "all") {
      $(".filter").show(2000);      // remove quotes
    } else {
      $(".filter").not("." + name).hide(2000);
      $(".filter").filter("." + name).show(2000);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="portfolio">
  <div style="text-align: center">
    <div class="navigation">
      <a href="" data-filter="all" class="button active">ALL</a>
      <a href="" data-filter="one" class="button">ONE</a>
      <a href="" data-filter="two" class="button">TWO</a>
      <a href="" data-filter="three" class="button">THREE</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ImageContainer">
      <div class="filter one">
        <img src="img/beach.jpg" width="400px" height="250px">
      </div>
      <div class="filter one">
        <img src="img/Windows.jpg" width="400px" height="250px">
      </div>
```